# Dummy Variables in a Regression setting

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have data with several dummy variables $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ and a dependent variable $y$.
Imagine I want to do an analysis with just a subset of the dummy variables $\{x_{\pi_1(1)},...,x_{\pi_m(k)}\}$.
Should I use all the observations of the dependent variable $y$, or just those that belong to the subset of dummy variables $\Pi(y)$? Why?

I know that the OLS estimates in both possibilities will be equal, but not the standard errors, which will give me different confidence intervals, t-statistics, etc.

For example: My $y$ is income of a given sample of individuals, which are divided among 3 non-intersecting groups(G1,G2,G3). Let's suppose I want to run a regression of income on $\text{Dummy}_{G3}$ only. Should I use $y$, or $y_{G3}$ i.e. only the income corresponding to individuals in G3?

```
G1  G2  G3  Income
0   0   1   569.5
0   0   1   895.5
0   0   1   1111
0   0   1   1182
0   0   1   1277.5
0   0   1   1384
0   0   1   1464.5
0   0   1   2453
0   0   1   2538
0   0   1   2539.5
0   0   1   2830.5
0   0   1   2852
0   0   1   2865
0   0   1   2945
0   0   1   3023
0   0   1   3024.5
```

The data continues. I have approximately 4500 observations. $\text{Dummy}_{G1}+\text{Dummy}_{G2}+\text{Dummy}_{G3}=\mathbf{1}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you used a complete data set, what would be the values of a subset in it? Are they missing? What do you mean by "belong to" in this context?

Comment: When you say "all the observations of the dependent variable $y$", do you mean all of the dummy variables?

Comment: @Aksakal I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I've edited the question.

Comment: @caveman I've edited the question.

Comment: show an example of data set, a few rows maybe. it's still not clear what's up with dummies in three subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the distribution of observations in the groups G1, G2, and G3.

Classically, regression/classification algorithms were only trained by related samples in G3 (since you want to predict income of folks in G3 only).

But it turns out that looking at folks in G1 and G2 can help you better learn about folks in G3 as well.

There is a thing called *multi-task learning*, that you may need to read about, where you learning for other tasks in addition to your main task in order to enhance your model's understanding about the main task.